# R: ggplot for hover text

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

My data (final.df) looks like the following:

```
A B C Y 1     
0 0 0 0 0.05 
0 0 1 1 0.03 
....
```

Based on the comment below, here is a ASCII text representation of the dataframe.

```
structure(list(A = c(502, 541, 542, 543, 544, 545, 4304, 4370, 
4371, 4372, 4373, 4442), B = c(4.4, 4.2, 4.4, 4.6, 4.8, 5, 5.2, 
4.6, 4.8, 5, 5.2, 5.2), C = c(2.6, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 12.6, 
12.8, 12.8, 12.8, 12.8, 13), Y = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1), `1` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `NA` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000281600479875937, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "Y", "1", NA), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

To summarize, there are four columns that identify each data point. I am interested in creating two boxplots according to their values in column with name 1. I want to compare the values for points labeled 0 in column 'Y' and labeled 1 in column 'Y'. Finally, I want to be able to hover over the points to retrieve the meta-data, meaning the 'A', 'B', 'C', and '1' value.

```
p <- ggplot(final.df, aes(x = factor(Y), y = 
Y, fill = factor(Y))) 
p <- p + geom_boxplot() + geom_point() + xlab("Y") + guides(fill = 
guide_legend("Y")) + theme(legend.position="top") 
final.p <- ggplotly(p)
```

The current plot shows me factor(Y) value and the corresponding value in 1. How can I include the meta-data in columns 'A', 'B', 'C'?

Comment: Using `dput()`, can you add `final.df` to your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can build a text using `paste0` and HTML tag `<br><\br>` and instructe `toolttip` to use text.

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Y), y = Y, 
                    fill = factor(Y), text=paste('</br>A: ',A,'</br>B: ',B, '</br>1: ',1)))

ggplotly(p,tooltip = c("text"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `tooltip` feature of `ggplotly`. Read about it by typing in `help(ggplotly)`. See Below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

set.seed(55)
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(rep(0, 8), rep(1, 8)),
  B = rep(c(rep(0, 4), rep(1, 4)), 2),
  C = rep(c(rep(0, 2), rep(1, 2)), 4),
  Y = rep(c(0, 1), 8),
  X1 = runif(16)
)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Y), y = X1, fill = factor(Y), A = A, B = B, C = C))
p <- p + geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("Y") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend("Y")) +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
final.p <- ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("A", "B", "C"))
final.p
```